# Reading from the same URL multiple times,not getting the data 2nd time

Tags: java, http, url, inputstream, httpurlconnection

I have the following code.A connection,then getting an input stream from that connection and reading from the input stream.Now I want to reuse the same connection to get input stream one more time,but second time I am not getting any data.

Why is that so?I am not using the same stream but the same connection.Do we need to open the connection again 2nd time?Please explain.

```
URL url=new URL("https://www.google.co.in/");
HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection=(HttpURLConnection)
url.openConnection();
httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
httpURLConnection.connect();

InputStream inputStream=httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
String inputLine;
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
System.out.println(inputLine);

System.out.println("**********************************");


/*Reading 2nd time*/
InputStream is=httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
String inputLines=null;
while ((inputLine = bf.readLine()) != null) 
System.out.println(inputLines);
bf.close();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `getInputStream()` a second time won't give you a new stream, it will just give you the one that you've already read - and that stream has nothing left to read.

If you really want to read the content twice, I suggest you copy it to a `String` (or to a `byte[]` if its content is not text) the first time you read it.  You can then read it twice from the `String` or from the `byte[]`.

Another alternative, if the content is particularly large, would be to copy it off to a temporary file.

Comment: I want to check what is the instance of HttpURLConnection actually referring to.In the above code if after printing the asterisks.I make a call to httpUrlConnection.connect again then also I donot get the input stream.Why is that so?

Comment: Hirak's answer explains that.

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting data because there is nothing in the stream. To get it, you have to send another "GET" request

Comment: the "GET" request is sent by connect() method or openconnection() method ?

Comment: If connect makes the actual "GET" REQUEST then if we connect again using the same httpUrlCpnnection instance,why we donot get the results in that case?

Answer (score 0):

> Each HttpURLConnection instance is used to make a single request

Please refer the javadoc

http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html

Answer (score -1):

Why you want to read it multiple times? Just keep the values in a variable.

```
List<String> inputLines =new ArrayList<String>();
String inputLine;
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
inputLines.add(inputLine);
```